# MS Access ADODB Returns Wrong Output Value

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, ms-access, adodb

I am executing a SQL Server stored procedure in MS Access using ADODB.Command. The procedure inserts a record and returns the new record's ID through an output parameter. It will return the correct ID if the size of the text in one of the parameter is below a certain length. If the text size is above a certain length it will return a large seemingly random number like, 646892128. In this case the procedure still executes and the record is created properly on the server but Access gets the wrong output value back. This is very odd behavior and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCommunication]
@SponsorID NVARCHAR(255),
@SponsorName NVARCHAR(255),
@Year NVARCHAR(255),
@BudgetNumber NVARCHAR(255),
@BudgetName NVARCHAR(255),
@CommunicationDate datetime2(0),
@CommunicationText NVARCHAR(MAX),
@CommunicationID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Communication(SponsorID, SponsorName, Year, BudgetNumber, BudgetName, CommunicationDate, CommunicationText)
                             VALUES(@SponsorID, @SponsorName, @Year, @BudgetNumber, @BudgetName, @CommunicationDate, @CommunicationText);

    SET @CommunicationID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

Here is the Access VBA code executing the procedure:

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = strServerConnection
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandText = "InsertCommunication"
            .NamedParameters = True
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@SponsorID", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, Forms!frm_InvoiceInfo!txtSpnID)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@SponsorName", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, Forms!frm_InvoiceInfo!txtSpnName)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Year", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, strYear)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@BudgetNumber", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, Forms!frm_InvoiceInfo!txtBudget)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@BudgetName", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, Forms!frm_InvoiceInfo!txtBudgetName)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@CommunicationDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , Me.txtCommDate)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@CommunicationText", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, Me.txtCommChange)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@CommunicationID", adInteger, adParamOutput)
            .Execute
        End With
```

The size of the text passed into the `@CommunicationText` parameter is causing `@CommunicationID` to sometimes return a random number. It happens when the size of the text reaches around 5000 characters.

I have added `SET NOCOUNT ON`. I have executed the procedure directly in SSMS with the large text and it returns the correct output. So I'm thinking the problem is in Access but I have no idea what would cause Access to take the output and change the value.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is causing this behavior?

Edit:
Here is the connection string

```
ODBC;Description=f;DRIVER=SQLServer;SERVER=myServer;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=myApp;DATABASE=myDB
```

Comment: We need a [mre] i.e. an exact example that reproduces the issue. And what happens when you run the exact failing query in SSMS?

Comment: @DaleK I will try to provide an example. The query doesn't actually fail though, the only problem is that Access will sometimes produce the wrong value in the output parameter.

Comment: Thats what I mean by fail... it fails to work as you require

Comment: What is your connection driver/provider? Have you tried putting the nvarchar(max) as last in the procedure (..the output int parameter before the nvarchar (max))

Comment: Please edit your question to include your connection string (obscure sever name, username and password if required) and the provider name (if that's not in the connection string).

Comment: @lptr I have added the connection string. No I haven't tried moving the parameter. I didn't think the parameter order would make a difference.